# Delete last line in console to write shorter message python

Tags: python, console, stdout

I would like to have a loop with the messages in console line:

```
load.
load..
load...
load.
load..
```

and so on.

I don't want to use '\r'. Because it does not clear the whole line.
Any ideas?

Comment: using `print(your_statement,end='\r', flush=True)` will clear the line when next will comeup. may be you forgetting `flush=True`. or you can use `os.system('clear')` or `os.system('cls')` as per your operating system

Comment: flush can not be helpful, and os.system('clear') clear all cmd

Answer (score 0):

If it is not clearing the line, You can always pad it with whitespace. like this:

```
import sys
import time

while True:
    for i in range(1,4):
        print("\rLoading"+ "".join(["."]*i)+"".join([" "]*(4-i)),end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
```

or else use a library like [progressbar2](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/)