# How to flush entire row when printing status

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
import time

print("some previous print", end='\r', flush=True)

for i in range(10):
    print("progress " + str(i), end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The result is something like `progress 9ous print` - so it just cuts previous print by length.

I could have something like `end='          \r'` to make length longer, but not ideal and flexible solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\r in Python does not delete the entire line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660820/r-in-python-does-not-delete-the-entire-line)

Comment: What is your expected/wanted output?

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi Exactly! Thank you. I wonder I have not found it myself (I was searching for a while).

Comment: See also [`progressbar2` and deleting line in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954472/delete-last-line-in-console-to-write-shorter-message-python)

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

- prepend an additional [carriage-return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers) (CR or `\r`) before the output-string
- and make sure all previous printed characters are over-written (if necessary by space):

```
import time

print("About to start shortly.", end='\r', flush=True)
time.sleep(3)
print(" "*50, end='\r', flush=True) # overwritting a length of 50 with space

for i in range(10):
    print(f"\rprogress {i:2}", end='\r', flush=True)  # prefixed with CR, f-string right-aligned
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note: the status-lines have a constant width of 11 (9+ 2 digits reserved for the number, right-aligned).